# NSubstitute multiple return sequence

Tags: nsubstitute

I want to substitute object to return sequence of different objects.
For example:

```
var http = Substitute.For<IHttp>();
http.GetResponse(Arg.Any<string>()).Returns(resourceString, resourceString2);
http.GetResponse(Arg.Any<string>()).Returns(x => { throw new Exception(); });
```

will return resourceString then resourceString2 then exception.

Or something like this:

```
var http = Substitute.For<IHttp>();
http.GetResponse(Arg.Any<string>()).Returns(resourceString, x => { throw new Exception(); }, resourceString2);
```

will return resourceString then exception then resourceString2.

How can I do that?

Comment: I've made a [pull request](https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/pull/100) to the NSubstitute to support that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

***This answer is outdated — NSubstitute has direct support for this now. Please see [@dangerdex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38424249/906) to this question for more information.***

---

The multiple returns syntax in NSubstitute only supports values. To also throw exceptions you'll need to pass a function to `Returns`, and implement the required logic yourself (e.g. `Returns(x => NextValue())`).

There is a related example for [Moq sequences on Haacked's blog](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/11/24/moq-sequences-revisited.aspx) using a queue. You can do a similar thing with NSubstitute (example code only, use at your own risk :)):

```
public interface IFoo { int Bar(); }

[Test]
public void Example() {
    var results = new Results<int>(1)
                    .Then(2)
                    .Then(3)
                    .Then(() => { throw new Exception("oops"); });
    var sub = Substitute.For<IFoo>();
    sub.Bar().Returns(x => results.Next());

    Assert.AreEqual(1, sub.Bar());
    Assert.AreEqual(2, sub.Bar());
    Assert.AreEqual(3, sub.Bar());
    Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => sub.Bar());
}

public class Results<T> {
    private readonly Queue<Func<T>> values = new Queue<Func<T>>();
    public Results(T result) { values.Enqueue(() => result); }
    public Results<T> Then(T value) { return Then(() => value); }
    public Results<T> Then(Func<T> value) {
        values.Enqueue(value);
        return this;
    }
    public T Next() { return values.Dequeue()(); }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 37):

This is now a supported feature in NSubstitute with a very friendly interface.

It would be something like...

```
var http = Substitute.For<IHttp>();
http.GetResponse(Arg.Any<string>()).Returns(
  x => resourceString,
  x => resourceString2,
  x => { throw new Exception(); }
);
```

[Documentation can be found here](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/multiple-returns/)

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example that does everything inline without an extra class. If you were doing this a lot I would probably go with the separate class option.

```
[Test]
public void WhenSomethingHappens()
{
    var something = Substitute.For<ISomething>();
    int callCount = 0;
    something.SomeCall().Returns(1, 2);
    something.When(x => x.SomeCall()).Do(obj => { if (++callCount == 3) throw new Exception("Problem!"); });

    Assert.AreEqual(1, something.SomeCall());
    Assert.AreEqual(2, something.SomeCall());
    Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => something.SomeCall());
}


public interface ISomething
{
    int SomeCall();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the way with extra class seems more easier to read and implement.

Answer (score 0):

Another example with out parameter.
Moreover it is usueful for some scenarios when function is called periodically in separated thread. We can simulate/mock each call differently.

```
   List<AnyClass> items = new List<AnyClass>();

   mockIService.TryDoSth(out response).ReturnsForAnyArgs(p =>
            {
                p[0] = items;
                return true;
            }, 
            p =>
            {
                p[0] = items;
                return true;
            }, p =>
            {
                throw new Exception("Problem!"); 
            });
```

bool TryDoSth(out List result);