# NSubstitute: Setup a mocked method to fail on the first call, and succeed on the second

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, nsubstitute

How can I use NSubstitute to mock a method that will throw an exception the first time it is called, then succeed the second time it is called?

I know there is an answer for Moq. But I am using NSubstitute.

I wish there was a way like this:

```
restClient.GetAsync<FieldResponse>("url").
                .Throws(new Exception("error")) // I want to get exception at first call
                .Returns(Task.FromResult(fakeFieldResponse)); // I want to get a value at second call
```

Comment: NUnit is the assertion framework, not a mocking library. You can't compare Moq & NUnit

Comment: I think it's helps, please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62640655/mock-a-method-twice-with-nsubstitute-to-first-throw-error-and-later-return-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Returns` method supports returning multiple values. One of these *"returns"* can throw an exception.

The second sample [on this page in the official docs](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/multiple-returns/) describes what you need. Your sample will look similar to this:

```
restClient
   .GetAsync<FieldResponse>("url")
   .Returns(x => throw new Exception("error"), x => Task.FromResult(fakeFieldResponse));
```

Comment: Thanks @yan-sklyarenko it doesn't work. I always get null.

Comment: It was not working for another error in my code.